# meeting on a weekly-basis

Tags: meaning

I would like to inquire about the meaning of "daily-basis" , "weekly-basis" ...etc. 
For example

```
I would like to meet with you on a weekly basis
```

Does this sentence means that the meeting will happen every week at the same day and the same time, or just every week anyday/anytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meeting on a weekly basis only requires that you meet each week. The meeting can be held:

- at a specific time and place, or
- at a specific time but different places, or
- at different times but the same place, or
- at different times and different places.

Where the meetings are held at different times and/or different places, the time and/or place for the next meeting will usually be decided before the end of the current meeting.

In a business context, weekly meetings are usually scheduled for a specific time and place.

Comment: +1 Although context almost always provides the answer, there is also the question of what "a week" means. At a company, it would typically be Monday through Friday, for instance. "Daily" seems pretty obvious, although somebody particular *might* think that meeting at 11 p.m. and then again in two hours would satisfy the condition. :)

Comment: @Jason Bassford  Agreed, it is sometimes advisable for all involved to ensure that there is a common agreement as to what is meant by 'a week'.